# The baking speed of multiple cloths dropped dramatically

Tags: texture-baking, baking, cloth-simulation, cache

I use Blender 3.6 for my Blender files, and the duration of the camera animation is 15000 frames. At the same time, there are nearly 200 cloths in it, along with one wind force, so I need to bake all of the cloths.

The difficulty I encountered is ：

initially, the baking speed was very fast and CPU usage could reach 100%.
However, after baking about 1/3, the baking speed started to slow down. In fact, the baking speed decreased exponentially. While the baking speed decreases, my CPU usage cannot reach 100% anymore ,only 20% to 50%.

I can't solve this problem, I want to know what the cause is and how I can avoid it.

I speculate that it could be either because there are too many cloth objects or because the animation with 15,000 frames is too long.?

**I don't understand, I need your help. Thank you.**

[image]

The following is my computer information:

blender 3.6
CPU：13600KF
RAM：128GB
Hard drive：SSD

In fact, the baking speed is rapidly decreasing, and for every 100 frames baked, the total completion time doubles.
↓：
[image]

Comment: To be honest, we are no developers here and not associated with the Blender Foundation, so this is probably not the right place to ask this question. Because I don't know how Blender is actually simulating those things, I can only guess the data accumulates the longer the simulation runs because usually each frame of a simulation is a result of the previous frame(s) and of course the cached data gets more and more.

Comment: i think your computer information doesn't help here. The question is: how many cloth with what resolution and how many collisions do you have? because this has all to be calculated. I just can assume, but i think the frame where it gets slower the first clothes are hitting some collisions, right? so that's pretty normal, that it is slowing down. If you provide your blend file, we could take a look. Cloth simulation can often be simplified by simplified cloth proxy cloth objects so that the simulation will be quicker.

Comment: The only thing I know is, simulations are even slowing down on my PC with one cloth and just 100 frames, so I think since your machine is not gigantic in performance, 200 cloth objects and 15.000 frames seems to be a ridiculous amount (at least if I would want to simulate it on my PC).

Comment: Yes, I tried doubling the breakdown of all cloths, which increased significantly at the beginning of baking, but dropped rapidly after 1/3 of the baking.
I have tried to divide the animation of 15,000 frames into three segments for baking. The first segment consists of frames 1-5000, the second segment consists of frames 5001-10000, and the third segment consists of frames 10001-15000.
The result is that the first and second paragraphs are very fast, with CPU usage at 100%. However, in the third paragraph, after baking 1/3, the speed noticeably decreases and CPU usage rapidly drops as well.

Comment: I initially speculate that the reason, as mentioned by Gordon Brinkmann, is because:
each frame of a simulation is a result of the previous frame(s) and of course the cached data gets more and more。

So where can I resize the cache?

Comment: Resize the cache? I mean the data of the simulation that is written to Blender's cloth cache. You cannot resize this. When you bake a simulation, you can see in the cloth settings how the simulation data per frame are written into the memory. For example, a simple piece of cloth with 4096 faces colliding with one object. The memory usage increases from 0 MB for 0 frames to 36.3 MB for 250 frames. Two objects, 72.6 MB. Now imagine 200 objects and 15.000 frames: 425 GB.